# Google Column Charts from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, charts, google-visualization, column-chart

I want to fetch data for today's sales from MySQL database. With the code below, I can only show one menu ID in the chart. I want to show it like there are S001, S002, S003, S004 and S005. The quantity of the items will be shown even it's zero.

```
function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Food');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
    data.addRows([
      <?php
        $i = 0;
        require "init.php";
        $menu_id = "S001";

        //query db
        $sql = "SELECT m.food_name, SUM(o.quantity) AS quantity FROM `Order` o INNER JOIN `Menu` m ON m.menu_id = o.FK_menu_id WHERE DATE(`ordered_on`) = CURDATE() AND o.FK_menu_id = '$menu_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $i++;
          echo "['".$row['food_name']."', ".$row['quantity']."]";
          if ($i < $row) {
            echo ",";
          }
        }
      ?>
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':"Today's Sales",
                   'width':600,
                   'height':450,
                   'legend':'none'};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

The figure is the output for current code:
[image]

Comment: Use `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` instead of `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable` like in google reference https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart .

Comment: @BitAccesser   But how to add S002, S003, S004 and S005 to the graph?

Comment: I am not sure want you want. If the cols should be named S001 to S005 instead of `SET A` Increment the `$menu_id`for each row of the array, else provide further info (pic).

Comment: @BitAccesser   I want the the graph to show `SET A` to `SET E` even the there is no data of `SET` E in the database.

Comment: Still confused! A the moment you set the column name to `$row['food_name']` (is this `Set A`?). If you want `$menu_id` instead you have to put it in the first field of `arrayToDataTable ` on each element of the array.

Comment: easiest way would be to adjust the sql, does the table `menu` hold all the names, regardless of `order`? if so, try using a `left outer join` vs. `inner`